# Is it Gerund or present participle?

Tags: gerunds

1) Setting goal may appear easy but it is quite challenging.
2) Quantifying goals provide specific ways to track progress 3)  Finding the right footing,precisely mastering the skills and getting to the next place,all depend on how we approach and tackle the problem.                                                  4)I like reading more than writing.                                                5)We are planning to execute our strategies.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about whether they are gerunds or present participles. Modern grammar doesn't use these terms, but simply lumps them together and calls them "gerund-participles". All the _ing_ forms in your examples are verbs (except "challenging" which is an adjective); that's really all you need to know.

Answer (score 2):

1) "Setting" is a gerund. "challenging" is an adjective.

2) "Quantifying" is a gerund.

3) "Finding", "mastering" and "getting" are all gerunds. "footing" is just a noun.

4) "reading" and "writing" are both gerunds.

5) "planning" is a present participle.